# What causes Serial.available() to become false after Serial.read() gets data?

Tags: serial, softwareserial, serial-data, buffer

As serial data bytes are being read from the serial buffer by `Serial.read()`, are they removed from the Arduino's 64-byte serial buffer altogether?

In my current situation I'm using SoftwareSerial, but this question applies to both software and hardware serial connections.

<sub>**EDIT:** *Based on a comment from **@dandavis**, I'd like to further clarify my question*</sub>

How does `Serial.read()` interact with `Serial.available()`? Let's say that I have the usual setup:

```
while( Serial.available() ) { 
    Serial.read();
}
```

What causes `Serial.available()` to become `false`?

<sub>**EDIT 2:** *Changed question title for even further clarification...*</sub>

Comment: the only way you can "remove" a byte, is to overwrite it. ... i do not think that the library code does that, because that would be a waste of resources. ... i'm sure that the pointer into the buffer is the only thing that has changed.

Comment: yes, you read() until available() is false, at which point the buffer is considered empty.

Comment: What do you mean by "removed"?

Comment: See the Wikipedia article [Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). It has some figures and an animation that should help you understand how it works.

Comment: If they weren't, you would only ever be able to receive 64 bytes. Does that sound logical?

Comment: @dandavis Thank you for that clarification - That was pretty much what I was asking, but couldn't figure out how to ask (terribly sorry).I suppose it would have been best to phrase the question as 'How does `Serial.available()` go from `true` to `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating how many bytes are available for reading:

```
int HardwareSerial::available(void)
{
  return ((unsigned int)(SERIAL_RX_BUFFER_SIZE + _rx_buffer_head - _rx_buffer_tail))
}
```

It's so simple.

Have a look at the Arduino subdir (in your disk) `hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino`. The HardwareSerial.cpp is where you have to look at.

Answer (score 2):

It is an internal buffer and only the pointer gets increased. It it visible in the source code off the project, located on [github](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/2bfe164b9a5835e8cb6e194b928538a9093be333/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.cpp):

```c
// Read data from buffer
int SoftwareSerial::read()
{
  if (!isListening())
    return -1;

  // Empty buffer?
  if (_receive_buffer_head == _receive_buffer_tail)
    return -1;

  // Read from "head"
  uint8_t d = _receive_buffer[_receive_buffer_head]; // grab next byte
  _receive_buffer_head = (_receive_buffer_head + 1) % _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF;
  return d;
}
```

This third line from the bottom is the important part, it wraps back to the beginning if the buffer space has run out. If you call `Serial.read()`, the pointer is moved to the next position. So with the next `Serial.read()`, you'll get the next byte, if available. The byte itself gets overwritten only after the wrap (circular buffer).

Comment: That's call a `circular buffer`.

Comment: You wrote: “_The byte itself gets never overwritten_”. It does, eventually, [when that buffer cell is reused for storing a new incoming byte](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/2bfe164b9a5835e8cb6e194b928538a9093be333/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.cpp#L175).

Comment: @EdgarBonet. The moment the pointer advanced, the byte disappears, it's not longer there, it doesn't exists anymore from the perspective of the running code.